# How message can be decoded into form as given

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a activemq message that is recieved by consumer as given below:

> `0327700000260000460000010000047000108Full TalkValue Offer! Get talkvalue of Rs.62 on Recharge of Rs.62.Yourlast Call Charge is 1.000.Your Main Balance is Rs 47.000.00001500001291965355668000001800001604952312808659f9`

I have to decode this message into following format using java:

```
DIALOG : 032770
MESSAGE : 000026
Parameter : 000046 [ UNKNOWN ] Length : 1
Value : 0
Parameter : 000047 [ UNKNOWN ] Length : 108
Value : FullTalkValueOffer!GettalkvalueofRs.62onRechargeofRs.62.YourlastCallChargeis1.000.YourMainBalanceisRs47.000.
Parameter : 000015 [ MSISDN ] Length : 12
Value : 919653556680
Parameter : 000018 [ UNKNOWN ] Length : 16
Value : 04952312808659f9
```

The message is decoded using following rule:
First 6 characters of message are DIALOG and next 6 characters are MESSAGE.
After that it will choose next 6 characters as parameter.And will search for length  in next 6 characters.It will neglect 0 and it will pick 1.If at any position in these 6 characters it will pick that and length will be digits after 1 along with 1.And according to this length,it will pick next characters of the message as value.
After that it will choose next parameter and corresponding length and value.

I have already decoded dialog and message using substring method of String .But i can'nt find logic to decode further message..plz anybody tell me the logic..

Comment: The length `108` does not match the length of the string `FullTalkValue...`. It looks a little strange, so maybe some unprintable characters got removed or replaced by something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Message {
    public int dialog;
    public int message;
    public Map<Integer, String> parameters;

    public Message(String input) {
        int pos = 0;
        dialog = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(pos,pos+6));
        pos += 6;
        message = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(pos,pos+6));
        pos += 6;
        parameters = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();
        while (pos+12 <= input.length())
        {
            int param = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(pos,pos+6));
            pos += 6;
            int len = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(pos,pos+6));
            pos += 6;
            parameters.put(param, input.substring(pos,pos+len));
            pos += len;
        }
    }
}
```

```
Message msg = new Message(input);

System.out.printf("DIALOG : %d\n", msg.dialog);
System.out.printf("MESSAGE : %d\n", msg.message);
for (Integer param : msg.parameters.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("PARAM %d : \"%s\"\n", param, msg.parameters.get(param));
}
```

Comment: how value will be calculated??